# Name, Email from Google's OAuth API

Tags: oauth, google-api

I want to allow users to login with google on a site and collect their name and email address but I can't find any documentation on the userinfo scope for google's api: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use 
    http://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/ and    https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo#email as the scope of the request tokens.

The protected resource url is
https://www-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/api/people/@me/@self to get the current user's data.

I get the user's G+ profile and name. I'm not able yet to get the user's email but I think i'm close

Comment: I was trying to get email using this plugin called Hello.js . It retrieves id name but for email it says undefined.

Answer (score 65):

This is a better way to get the name and email.

Set your scopes to:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email

and

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile

And use the endpoint:

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json

That will get you all you need!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I needed. For other's reference this http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/index.php is extremely helpful for figuring out your Google OAuth scopes.

Comment: separate the scopes with a space - for someone who might now know

Answer (score 8):

Retrieve OAuth userinfo using the Google Python API:

https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

```
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)

users_service = build('oauth2', 'v2', http=http)
user_document = users_service.userinfo().get().execute()
```

Comment: Why vote this answer down? Work perfectly, solved my problem. I was using G+ API and I wanted the user's email as well, I just needed to do a request with oauth2. Thanks !

Comment: In order for this to work it is necessary to set the data-scope attribute of the Google+ sign in button with the scopes mentioned in the Jonathan Mabe answer.

Answer (score 2):

A client-side Javascript SDK for authenticating with OAuth2 (and OAuth1 with a oauth proxy) web services and querying their REST API's. HelloJS Standardizes paths and responses to common API's like Google Data Services, Facebook Graph and Windows Live Connect. Its modular so that list is growing. No more spaghetti code!

http://adodson.com/hello.js/

Answer (score 1):

With the latest OAuth 2 draft support, Google provides Google ID tokens, an OpenID Connect implementation which - if you include the scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile and https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email - will supply the email address (see the class `GoogleIdToken` in the latest Java API). Unfortunately, though, this doesn't provide the user's name. But it is a way that requires fewer roundtrips, if you can make do with just the email address.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a php example using Google code how to get users details

....
$oauth2Service = new Google_Oauth2Service($client);
var_dump($oauth2Service->userinfo->get());
...

Bellow is the class from google
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/source/browse/trunk/src/contrib/Google_Oauth2Service.php